# Ubuntu keeps crashing on my Dell Inspiron-15 laptop

Tags: dell, crash

As soon as I received my laptop a month ago, I installed Ubuntu on it. I do lots of multitasking on my laptop, and always have few browser windows open (about 2 to 4 at a time), and sometimes a program/terminal or two.

Frequently, I open the laptop to find out it crashed (just stopped working, frozen). It never happens WHILE I'm using it, only sometimes when I open it.

My laptop's specs:

- **RAM:** 7.7GB
- **Graphics card:** Intel HD Graphics 5500
- **Processor:** Intel i5-5200U 2.20GHz (64-bit processor)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of bug reports of the Inspiron 15 not resuming after suspend.

Here's one:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1331654